# Trying to pull data from a SODA API into Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

The API call looks like this:
https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/3pdp-qp95.json?house_number=10008&street_name=103%20STREET%20NW

and returns data in json:
[{"account_number":"3070208","garage":"N","house_number":"10008","latitude":"53.539158992619","longitude":"-113.497760691896","neighbourhood":"DOWNTOWN","street_name":"103 STREET NW","tax_class":"Non Residential","total_asmt":"1717000"}]

I have an excel table with specific house_number and street_name pairs and I want to capture the total_asmt column for each pair.

I've been able to create a power query which pulls the very first data point into a new sheet:

```
let
  Parameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Parameter,{"house_number", "street_name"}),
  X = #"Removed Other Columns"[house_number]{0},
  Y = #"Removed Other Columns"[street_name]{0},
  Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/3pdp-qp95.json?house_number="& X &"&street_name=" & Y)),
in
  Source
```

I can't figure out how to iterate through all the value I have in X and Y or how to capture specific rows from the JSON data. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Aaleem

Answer (score 0):

I think your best best is to *not do it*.

***Why*** are you wasting your time scraping this data one address at a time when you could have the entire city's data in under a minute.

- JSON: https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/3pdp-qp95.json
- CSV: https://data.edmonton.ca/api/views/q7d6-ambg/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD
- XML: https://data.edmonton.ca/api/views/q7d6-ambg/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD

  *...among others.*  Heck, they even have [image: RSS] !

And when you're done with that one, they have a few hundred other interesting datasets.

Comment: Although in this case you are probably right as the data I am pulling is essentially static -- I may also pull some data from a similar but different MLS API (where the data is more dynamic) so I'd still like to know how to do it!

Comment: I'm confused -- isn't the data I'm trying to pull from an API? So what's the proper method of accessing this API data and working with it in excel -- certainly not pulling all the data...?

Comment: @aajiwa - sorry, that was my last comment of the night and it apparently made more sense in my head at the time.  (I deleted it.)

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to create a function inside powerquery, and then use the query as part of a table. Create the function as below and then under the data tab select your table using "From Table/Range" from there it is pretty straight forward.

```
let a_value= (x as number,y as text)=> //this creates the function

let //this is essentially the query I wanted with some minor changes from above
  x_text = Number.ToText(x, "D", ""),
  Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://data.edmonton.ca/resource/3pdp-qp95.json?house_number="&x_text&"&street_name="&y)),
  Source1 = Source{0},
  total_asmt = Source1[total_asmt]
in
  total_asmt

in a_value //closes the function
```